# Получить сбалансированную выборку Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть выборка:

`A  B   C
423 42  3
423 42  3
423 4432    3
4423    432 4
43  332 4
2   42  4
32  44  4
22  3344    2
234 442 2`

Нужно получить настраиваемую выборку с N числов строк для каждого уникального значения из столбца С:
Например, получить по три строки с значением 3,4 в столбце С. то есть получим:

`A  B   C
423 42  3
423 42  3
423 4432    3
43  332 4
2   42  4
32  44  4`

Или же получить максимально возможную сбалансированную выборку, то есть по два элемента из каждого значения, т.к. "2" встретилась лишь два раза. Получим нечто такое:

`A  B   C
423 42  3
423 42  3
4423    432 4
43  332 4
22  3344    2
234 442 2`

Причем выбор двух строк с другими значениями осуществляется случайно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1.groupby('C').head(3)
      A     B  C
0   423    42  3
1   423    42  3
2   423  4432  3
3  4423   432  4
4    43   332  4
5     2    42  4
7    22  3344  2
8   234   442  2

df1.groupby('C').head(df1.groupby('C').size().min())
      A     B  C
0   423    42  3
1   423    42  3
3  4423   432  4
4    43   332  4
7    22  3344  2
8   234   442  2
```

Comment: Первый код делает не совсем то, что нужно, должно остаться без двоек. И вообще необохидима возможность устанавливать size для каждого из классов в `C`

Comment: @Max52, `"необохидима возможность устанавливать size для каждого из классов в C"` - можете привести в вопросе соответствующий пример?

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос заключается в том как оставить нужное количество строк (число строк может отличаться для разных групп) в каждой группе, то это можно сделать так:

Словарь содержащий информацию о количестве строк для каждой группы (в качестве ключей используем значения столбца `C`, в качестве значений число строк в группе):

```
In [21]: d = {3:2, 4:3, 2:1}

In [22]: (df.groupby("C", sort=False)
            .apply(lambda x: x.head(d[x.name]))
            .reset_index(drop=True))
Out[22]:
      A     B  C
0   423    42  3
1   423    42  3
2  4423   432  4
3    43   332  4
4     2    42  4
5    22  3344  2
```

Comment: Именно то, что хотел, спасибо!

Comment: А будет ли разница в зависимости от типо в столбце С ?

Comment: @Max52, повторюсь: "в качестве ключей используем значения столбца `C`"

Comment: Вроде все также на своих данных попробовал, keyerror : 5 выдает(

Comment: @Max52, алгоритм действий вам известен - открываете новый SO вопрос с __воспроизводимым__ примером данных)

Comment: @Max52, что вы хотите видеть на выходе для тех групп, для которых отсутствует правило в словаре `d`?

Comment: Ничего, просто их не брать в выборку. Видимо в этом проблема, куча других категорий еще есть, от которых сложно почистить, можно их просто не учитывать?

Comment: @Max52, просто отфильтруйте DataFrame перед группировкой

Comment: Каким именно образом ? Через str.match пробовал, но чето не очень результат. `16` и `16 текст` за одно и то же принимает